# Regedit key is not found

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, regedit, acl, syntax

Powershell:

```
$paths = @(  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\PnpLockdownFiles\%SystemRoot%/System32/drivers/3ware.sys"
)
    
foreach($path in $paths)
{
    cmd.exe /c "C:\SetACL.exe -on ""$path"" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr ""n:%username%"" -rec Yes" | Out-Null
    cmd.exe /c "C:\SetACL.exe -on ""$path"" -ot reg -actn ace -ace ""n:%username%;p:full"" -rec Yes" | Out-Null
}
```

Information about the SetACL.exe file can be found here.
https://helgeklein.com/setacl/

**This is a key, not a value.**

```
%SystemRoot%/System32/drivers/3ware.sys
```

There is a percent mark and slash.

There is such a regedit key, but I get this key not found error because of the <**%**> and <**/**> signs I mentioned.

I have searched and tried how to write them correctly but without success.

Things I've tried:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\PnpLockdownFiles\%%SystemRoot%%/System32/drivers/3ware.sys`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\PnpLockdownFiles\%%SystemRoot%%//System32//drivers//3ware.sys`

Comment: You really should address this question to the developer of SetACL. Why are you using CMD instead of directly running SetACL?

Comment: This is not the fault of the program. It's because of my ignorance.
"SetACL" was the tool I originally wanted to use. This problem also occurred when using "Reg Query".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used cmd.exe, which is expanding the `%SystemRoot%` probably back to `C:\WINDOWS`. Avoid CMD.EXE and call directly from Powershell - you'll need to swap `%USERNAME%` too. Something like this, replacing  `%` and the double escaped `"`:

```
$paths = @(  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\PnpLockdownFiles\%SystemRoot%/System32/drivers/3ware.sys"
)

foreach($path in $paths)
{
    C:\SetACL.exe -on "$path" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr "n:$env:USERNAME" -rec Yes
    C:\SetACL.exe -on "$path" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:$env:USERNAME;p:full" -rec Yes
}
```

Note that I'm not able to test the above, so I'll wipe this answer if no help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even just pasting the codes in place of mine worked fine.